# Question about partial orders in set theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$A,B$ are members of $\mathcal{P}({1,2,3,4})$.

The relation $S$ is defined by $ASB$ if and only if:

$A\cup\{1,2\}$ is contained in $B\cup\{1,2\}$.

Find the minimal and maximal elements of $ASB$.

So it seems to me if $B$ is a subset of $\mathcal{P}({1,2})$ then every $A$ is incomparable to $B$.

So how do I order the set?

Comment: I'm having a tough time reading what you're asking. $A, B \subset \mathcal{P}(\{1,2,3,4\})$ and $S$ is a relation defined by $A S B$ if and only if $A \cup \{1,2\} \subset B \cup \{1,2\}$. Is that correct?

Comment: @GaryMoon A,B are elements in P({1,2,3,4}), not subsets.
The rest is correct.

Comment: Right, that was a dumb typo on my part. Got it.

Comment: The empty set is comparable to any B.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience let $\mathscr{P}=\wp(\{1,2,3,4\})$. The relation $S$ on $\mathscr{P}$ is easily seen to be reflexive and transitive, so it is a [*preorder*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder) (or *quasiorder*). It is not, however, antisymmetric, since $\varnothing\mathrel{S}\{0\}$ and $\{0\}\mathrel{S}\varnothing$, but $\varnothing\ne\{0\}$, so one has to be a bit careful about how *minimal* and *maximal* are defined. I will use [these definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_and_minimal_elements#Definition).

Suppose that $A,B\in\mathscr{P}$. Then $A\mathrel{S}B$ if and only if $A\cup\{1,2\}\subseteq B\cup\{1,2\}$, which is the case if and only if $A\subseteq B\cup\{1,2\}$ and $\{1,2\}\subseteq\{1,2\}$. Of course it’s always true that $\{1,2\}\subseteq\{1,2\}$, so $A\mathrel{S}B$ if and only if $A\subseteq B\cup\{1,2\}$. This means that if $A\subseteq\{1,2\}$, then $A\mathrel{S}B$ for **all** $B\in\mathscr{P}$.

Let $M\subseteq\{1,2\}$, and suppose that $A\mathrel{S}M$; then $A\subseteq M\cup\{1,2\}=\{1,2\}$, so $A\cup\{1,2\}=\{1,2\}=M\cup\{1,2\}$, and therefore $M\mathrel{S}A$, so $M$ is minimal with respect to $S$. Conversely, if $M\nsubseteq\{1,2\}$, then $\varnothing\mathrel{S}M$, since

$$\varnothing\cup\{1,2\}=\{1,2\}\subseteq M\cup\{1,2\}\,,$$

but $M\not\mathrel{S}\varnothing$, since

$$M\cup\{1,2\}\nsubseteq\{1,2\}=\varnothing\cup\{1,2\}\,,$$

so $M$ is not minimal with respect to $S$. This proves that the $S$-minimal elements are precisely the four subsets of $\{1,2\}$, i.e., $\varnothing,\{1\},\{2\}$, and $\{1,2\}$.

I will leave it to you to find the $S$-maximal elements, with this hint: for which $A\in\mathscr{P}$ is the set $A\cup\{1,2\}$ as large as possible?